# Fail to POST OneToOneField with Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner with Django and specially with the Django REST framework. 
I'm trying to POST a new user which contains user's settings.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime 
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())

class Address(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    streetName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
    zipCode = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)

class Settings(models.Model):
    cancelTime = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    onlyInWifi = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pseudo =  models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    settings = models.OneToOneField(Settings, null=True)
```

This is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import User
from api.models import Address
from api.models import Settings


class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('number', 'streetName', 'zipCode', 'city', 'country')

class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ('cancelTime', 'onlyInWifi')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address = AddressSerializer(required=False)
    settings = SettingsSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk','firstName', 'lastName', 'pseudo', 'mail', 'password', 'settings', 'address')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if(validated_data.get('address')):
            address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
            address = Address.objects.create(**address_data)
        else:
            address = None

        if(validated_data.get('settings')):
            settings_data = validated_data.pop('settings')
            settings = Settings.objects.create(**settings_data)
        else:
            settings = Settings()

        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)  
        user.address = address
        user.settings = settings
        return user
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'api.views',

    #Users
    url(r'^users/$', 'users_list', name='users_list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', 'user_detail', name='user_detail'),
}
```

And this is my views.py

```
import logging

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from api.models import User
from api.serializers import UserSerializer

#Users
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users_list(request):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def user_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Get, udpate, or delete a specific user
    """
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

When I'm try to post a new user, I have the behavior that I want

But when I load api/users to check if my user was well added, my settings field is null

I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: Can you add sample code showing what you're POSTing? Also, your `User` model allows `settings` to be null, is that correct?

Comment: Yes my settings can be null, but for example when I POST this : 
{
  "firstName" : "firstNameTest",
  "lastName" : "lastNameTest", 
  "pseudo" : "pseudoTest",
  "mail" : "test@gmail.com",
  "password" : "testPass",
  "user_settings" : {
       "cancelTime" : 50,
       "onlyInWifi" : true
  }

}
I have the behavior that I want but when I load api/users my settings are null in the user object that I have just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `serializers.py` file, you have to add your `settings` and `address` before to create your User object.

So replace this :

```
 user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)  
 user.address = address
 user.settings = settings
```

by :

```
validated_data['address'] = address;
validated_data['settings'] = settings;
user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```